# No query results for model - Laravel

Tags: laravel

I am creating a Laravel E-Commerce Project, but I'm experiencing a problem problem and receiving this error:

> App\Shop\Categories\Exceptions\CategoryNotFoundException No query results for model [App\Shop\Categories\Category] 2

Please let me know what I may be doing wrong?

Comment: you need to specify your situation in details. ex: your codes, database table structures etc.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `No query results for model` more often than not refers to a lack of an existent entry within the database. So basically, the model with `ID = 2` which you seem to be looking for there doesn't exist.